# Transfer data between uiviews in nil

Tags: ios, swift

Hi I'm trying to pass an object from one tableview controller to another one.
I'm using prepare for segue and a didselectRowAt function:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.myDish = sections[indexPath.section].listofDishes?[indexPath.row]
    self.sectionName = sections[indexPath.section].sectionName!

    self.flag = 1
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "chooseDish", sender: self)
}



override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if self.flag != 0{
    let selectedDishTableViewController = segue.destination as! SelectedDishViewController
        selectedDishTableViewController.sectionName = self.sectionName
        selectedDishTableViewController.dish = self.myDish

        self.flag = 0
    }
}
```

I created the flag because preparefor segue gets called before didselectrowat

Thant way I'm making sure to set myDish and sectionName before the prepare for segue.

by in my second view controller I still get both values as nil.

This is how I declare the vars in my second controller

```
var dish:Dish?
var sectionName:String?
```

Comment: It sounds like you have connedted a segue directly to your cells action in interface builder and you are trying to use perfromSegue. Remove the action segue. You can also supply your selected index path as the `sender` to your segue so that you can access it in `prepare`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If prepareForSegue is getting called before didSelectRow.., then it implies that the segue is already happening, so the second time when you force it to be invoked, by calling performSegue explicitly in didSelectRow <- it is ignored as the view controller has already been segued into with null values for those vars.

The solution here would be to do something like this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        let selectedDishTableViewController = segue.destination as! SelectedDishViewController
        selectedDishTableViewController.dish = sections[indexPath.section].listofDishes?[indexPath.row]
        selectedDishTableViewController.sectionName = sections[indexPath.section].sectionName!
    }
}
```

You don't have to do anything else in tableView:didSelect... for this, with this.. Lemme know if it works out.